# Web API validation error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, customvalidator

I have a View Model called SignUp with the EmailAddress property set like this:

```
 [Required]
 [DuplicateEmailAddressAttribute(ErrorMessage = "This email address already exists")]
 public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

and the custom validator looks like this:

```
public class DuplicateEmailAddressAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        PestControlContext _db = new PestControlContext();
        int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();

        if (value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (_db.Users.Where(x => x.EmailAddressHash == hash).Count() > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if the user leaves the email address field blank on the sign up form the application is throwing a null reference exception error (I think it's looking for "" in the database and can't find it). What I don't understand is why this isn't being handled by the Required attribute - why is it jumping straight into the custom validator?

Answer (score 0):

The `Required` attribute would have resulted in an error being added to the model state. It will not short-circuit the execution though. The framework continues to run other validators for the simple reason that **all** the errors about the request need to be sent out in a single shot. Ideally, you wouldn't want the service to say something is wrong to start with and when the user re-submits the request after making a correction, the service comes back and say some other thing is wrong and so on. It will be an annoyance, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The NullReferenceException is thrown because value.ToString() is called before the check against null. As you need the hash variable only after the check, you can solve this by reordering the statements:

```
if (value == null)
{
    return true;
}
int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();
```

In addition, you could also move the `PestControlContext` after the check against null and use a `using` statement to dispose of it properly.
As also @Baldri pointed out, each validator can add Error messages and all of them are run, even if a previous one already signaled the data to be invalid. Furthermore, I'd not rely on that the validations are run in the order that you specify when marking the property with the attributes (some frameworks implement their own attribute ordering mechanism in order to assert that the order is deterministic, e.g. priorities or preceding attributes).
Therefore, I suggest reordering the code in the custom validator is the best solution.